# Is there a way to modify the opacity value of a CSS background color with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css:

```
.class1 { background: #fff }
```

What I want is:

```
.class2 { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5) };
```

Is there any way that I can use ONLY JavaScript to modify the `background` property of `.class1`, to make it has a `opacity:.5` effect?

For example, I want something like this:

```
$('.class1').css('background-opacity', '.5');
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: can you share more context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably a function that would return RGBA from HTML color...

Could be something like that:

```
var color = $('.class1').css("background-color"); // this will return RGB() color even if it was html color before
var opacity = 0.5;
color = color.toString().replace(/\)/g,"," + opacity + ")");
$('.class1').css("background-color",color);
```

Live Fiddle in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hvkzpw09/).

Comment: This assumes that all `.class1` elements have the same background color to begin with, and it will apply an inline style, which will have different specificity than the original CSS rule

Comment: not sure what you mean? author asked to change opacity of already colored div

Comment: @Sean based on the context of the question by OP, this answers the question.

Comment: yeah... exactly... author doesn't want to change the color itself

Comment: @disinfor I don't disagree. Just wanted to note the limitation of this approach and the assumptions it makes.

Comment: My only interaction was to comment.

Comment: @Sean There isn't a limitation. This converts ANY color to the RGB value and sets the opacity. The assumptions are solely based on what the OP provided..which is valid. If the OP has more requirements, then I would agree, however, we haven't been provided any.

Comment: @disinfor If a more specific selector overrides the background color of `class1` for certain elements, this approach will change the color of the background back to a transparent version of the `class1` color. That's a limitation that should be noted.

Comment: @Sean agreed! OP should be aware of the inline-style specificity this will create.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for this.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");

div.addEventListener("click", () => {
  div.style.setProperty("--a", "0.5");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  --a: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, var(--a));
}
```

```html
<div>
  Click for opacity.
</div>
```

Comment: @Anthony click to the div

Comment: very nice solution; just wonder if the CSS modification is allowed per the OP

Comment: The question asks for a JS-only solution

Comment: but I love that solution anyway, I give it +1